# java, problema de log4j con hsqldb

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, log4j

Estoy usando JSF con HSQLDB 2.3.4 como base de datos. Al momento de ejecutar la búsqueda de un elemento arroja el siguiente error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (hsqldb.db..ENGINE).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

En mi aplicación no estoy usando log4j ni nada por el estilo. Lo raro es que antes este error no lo arrojaba. ¿Qué lo puede estar causando?

Este es mi archivo pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ar.edu.unlam.diit</groupId>
    <artifactId>scaw</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ar.edu.unlam.diit.scaw Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <dbcp.version>2.1</dbcp.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- connection polls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ESAPI Version 2.0.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- J2EE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>scaw</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ahora probé creando un log4j.properties

```
#log4j.rootLogger=FATAL, dest1
log4j.logger.dsaLogging=DEBUG, dsa
log4j.additivity.dsaLogging=false

log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p:%l: %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.ImmediateFlush=true

log4j.appender.dsa=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dsa.File=./logs/dsa.log
log4j.appender.dsa.MaxFileSize=2000KB
# Previously MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.dsa.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.dsa.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dsa.layout.ConversionPattern=%l:%d: %m%n
```

En esa ruta ya creé la carpeta y el archivo pero no me reconoce la ruta y al final arroja la misma advertencia. Al enviar la consulta por segunda vez funciona.

Con el log4j.properties tengo la siguiente excepción

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\logs\dsa.log (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:639)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:504)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger.getLog(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger.getLog(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getEventLogger(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.logInfoEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at ar.edu.unlam.diit.scaw.daos.impl.UsuarioDaoImpl.login(UsuarioDaoImpl.java:23)
at ar.edu.unlam.diit.scaw.services.impl.UsuarioServiceImpl.login(UsuarioServiceImpl.java:18)
at ar.edu.unlam.diit.scaw.beans.UsuarioBean.login(UsuarioBean.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Y la misma advertencia al final, el archivo está creado en la ruta que especifica.

Comment: Primero, no es un error es una advertencia (hay mucha diferencia allí). Segundo, necesitamos ver cómo has agregado las dependencias a tu proyecto. Si usas gradle o maven, por favor indica el archivo de configuración que usas. Solo así podremos comprender mejor dónde está tu problema y cómo resolverlo.

Comment: No "adjuntes" nada. Edita la pregunta y agrega tu pom allí.

Comment: Ya está editado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu pom, la dependencia esapi es la que contiene dependencias con log4j. Quizás antes no la tenías agregada en el proyecto, pero desde que la agregaste se agregaron esas dependencias "misteriosamente" (nada es un misterio realmente). Esto lo puedes confirmar aquí: [OWASP Project Dependencies](http://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder-esapi/dependencies.html)

Para configurar Log4j en tu proyecto, debes colocar el archivo log4j.properties en la raíz de tu carpeta src/main/resources. Allí tomará la configuración que estás indicando y con eso podrá desaparecer el warning (nuevamente, es advertencia, no es error).

---

Ahora te arroja un error de que no puede acceder al archivo en la ruta `./logs/dsa.log`. Considera que si la ruta empieza con `.` significa que va a buscar en la ruta actual de tu proyecto una carpeta `logs` y dentro va a crear un archivo dsa.log. Si no existe dicha carpeta, va a fallar. Lo más recomendable es brindar acceso a una carpeta que sabes que existe y que el usuario con el que ejecutes la aplicación tenga los permisos adecuados. Puesto que parece que estás en Windows, podrías probar usando algo como `C:/tmp/dsa.log`, y asegurarte de crear una carpeta `tmp` en la raíz del disco C.

Comment: Ahí edité, me tira error de que no se encuentra el archivo en la ruta que especifica, ya probé con rutas absolutas pero tampoco me lo reconoce.

Comment: Respuesta editada.

Comment: Ya creé el archivo en la ruta, cambié la ruta, ahora no arroja la excepción pero sigue arrojando la misma advertencia, probé tanto con barra como con doble barra invertida.

Comment: ¿Has agregado un appender para hsqldb.db..ENGINE tal como dice la advertencia?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, el mensaje desapareció.